# Azure AD B2C ROPC - Confidential client flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to implement a custom ROPC flow in b2c. The idea is that trusted ( internal ) applications can get user tokens without using its primary password ( the user may have several kinds of credentials ), but other credentials. 
I'm following the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga , but it clearly states:

> Confidential client flow: The application client ID is validated, but the application secret is not validated.

But, from my point of view, these flows should only be used by privileged clients, therefore B2C needs to validate the client_secret, but this is not an option.

Is there a workaround for that, maybe some parameter that I can use in my custom policy definition?

I know that this can be implemented using non ROPC flows, but some applications don't have a way to redirect the user to a web page ( like a TV App ).

Answer (score 1):

Use azure ad client credential flow, it works in B2C tenants too. If it must align to users, have a app reg for each user.

Server side ROPC will get throttled when using AAD B2C endpoint for ROPC policies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: If you check the app registration page, it says: Certificates (also referred as public keys) can be used as secrets to prove application's identity when requesting an Azure AD token. Certificates cannot be used to request Azure AD B2C tokens. We recommend using a certificate for client credential scenarios when authenticating against Azure AD

Comment: Also, where did you find the documentation saying that ROPC requests will get throttled?

Comment: What I am saying is, you need to use client credentials for your scenario, or AAD ROPC flow. Ideally the former. AAD B2C doesn’t support client credentials, nor does it support ROPC for servers (confidential clients) - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga#ropc-flow-notes). Essentially just treat your B2C directory as if it was AAD. Protect your API as if it was AAD, not for AAD B2C. You can do that by following AAD Docs against your AAD B2C directory.