# How to add a secret to "Resource Owner Password Credentials" B2C based app registraion on azure

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have an app registration on Azure that is being used to authenticate requests using the ROPC flow, so that we can mimick a real user access token and test our APIs. This is working, but to make this more secure we would like to be able to say a secret is required in the request.

This is not default for ROPC as it wasn't intended to be used with secrets (note - we **cannot** use client credentials for this part of testing we are doing).

The app registration is used along with a B2C user flow setup along side it. I don't *believe* this to be too relevant for this issue, but I could be wrong.

Currently the working call is as follows -

[image]

On azure to allow the ROPC flow you need to set the application to allow public flows.

[image]

I believe this setting stops any form of client secret or certificate being required in the request.

The microsoft docs seem to suggest it is possible to add a secret to ROPC calls and make them required but i can't figure out a way of doing it while having the above "public" azure setting set to true. With that off you get an error saying that the resource owner flow is not allowed due to it being private.

[image]

This is part of the Microsoft docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc which seems to suggest you might be able to make the app private, I just can't see how while allowing the flow.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) you mentioned is about Azure AD, but not Azure AD B2C. So there are two methods to get the access tokens with different formats. In addition, it's more secure for you to use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) in Azure Active Directory B2C.

---

One is following [AAD Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request) with your AAD B2C directory, see the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752247/13308381). Note: [`scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent) doesn't support application-id, it's related to the permissions in API Permissions.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{b2c-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id={b2c-application-id}
&scope=openid offline_access
&username={username}
&password={password}
&grant_type=password
&client_secret={client_secret, if your app is not a public client}
```

[image]

---

[**Recommend**] Another is [testing ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow#test-the-ropc-flow) in Azure AD B2C. `client_secret` is not in the parameters, so it is not required whether it is public or not.

```
https://{b2c-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{b2c-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{B2C_1_ROPC_Auth, name of ROPC flow}/oauth2/v2.0/token

username={username}
&password={password}
&grant_type=password
&scope=openid offline_access {b2c-application-id}
&client_id={b2c-application-id}
&response_type=token id_token
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @user3407039, does my reply help?